# How to access 'Is Featured Discussion' column in 'Management' view discussion board list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, discussion-board, list-column

I want to know whether,

- '***Is Featured Discussion***' column in **Discussion Board** List -->
  **Management View** is a ***Site Column*** or ***List Column*** ?
- How to access that column ?
- How to re-use that column in other lists other than Discussion Boards ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'**Is Featured Discussion**' column is a hidden site column and is grouped in "Custom Columns".

You can access the hidden site column via accessing a custom site column under "Custom Columns" group, then copying the URL of the custom site column, its URL should be like:

https://your site/_layouts/15/fldedit.aspx?**field=customSiteColumn**&Source=yoursitename2%2F%5Flayouts%2F15%2Fmngfield%2Easpx%3FFilter%3DCustom%2520Columns

Then change the **field** paramter of the url to **IsFeatured**, you will see the column setting page:
[image]

Per my knowledge, you are unable to re-use it in other lists except Discussions as the column is hidden and there is no way to change it.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It is really helpful.